# How do I convert 32-bit NEON assembly to 64-bit?

Tags: assembly, arm, neon

I am trying to use MSFA (googles music synth) on 64-bit iOS devices, and it has four NEON assembly source files for DSP operations that are apparently written for 32-bit architectures.  I was initially told that it would be better to rewrite this as NEON intrinsics so that it would be architecture-agnostic.  However, after reading some articles (such as http://hilbert-space.de/?p=22), it appears that it still is ideal to have this as pure hand written assembly.

My question is, is it trivial to convert this to 64-bit?  If so, how would I get started doing this?

The .s files are:

https://github.com/google/music-synthesizer-for-android/blob/master/cpp/src/neon_fir.s

https://github.com/google/music-synthesizer-for-android/blob/master/cpp/src/neon_fm_kernel.s

https://github.com/google/music-synthesizer-for-android/blob/master/cpp/src/neon_iir.s

https://github.com/google/music-synthesizer-for-android/blob/master/cpp/src/neon_ladder.s

Comment: See http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.den0024a/ch07s03.html and the other pages in that part of ARM's docs for some stuff about the changes to asm syntax for NEON, and the change to the register file.  (thirty-two 128b NEON registers, instead of the big regs being composed of pairs of smaller regs.)  See also [discussion here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38035351/rgba-to-abgr-inline-arm-neon-asm-for-ios-xcode/38040651?noredirect=1#comment63616468_38040651) about vector operand syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR: use intrinsics**

It's not a bad idea to check the asm output to make sure it's not dumb, but using intrinsics lets compilers do constant-propagation, and schedule / software-pipeline for in-order cores.

If you read the comment thread on [that post from 2009 you linked](http://hilbert-space.de/?p=22), you'd see that the bad code from NEON intrinsics was a [gcc bug fixed in 2011](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43118).

Compilers are quite good at handling intrinsics these days, and continually improving.  Clang especially can do quite a lot, like use different shuffle instructions than what you wrote with intrinsics.

At least they are for x86; **compilers for ARM still sometimes struggle with intrinsics**, especially when trying to access the two 8-byte halves of a 16-byte vector like you often want to in 32-bit ARM code for horizontal operations.  See *[ARM NEON intrinsics convert D (64-bit) register to low half of Q (128-bit) register, leaving upper half undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46910799/arm-neon-intrinsics-convert-d-64-bit-register-to-low-half-of-q-128-bit-regis)* / *[NEON intrinsic for sum of two subparts of a Q register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49511244/neon-intrinsic-for-sum-of-two-subparts-of-a-q-register)* - Jake Lee reports that as recently as 2018, some clang versions made a total mess out of it, but GCC6.x was not as bad.

This might not be as much of a problem with AArch64.

---

#### asm-level differences:

I'm not at all an expert on this, but one of the major NEON changes is that Aarch64 has thirty-two 128b NEON registers (`v0 - v31`), instead of each `q` register aliasing onto two `d` halves.

See also some [official ARM documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.den0024a/ch07s03.html) about syntax for element-size, where you can use `.16B` to indicate a vector of 16 byte elements.  (As opposed to [the old syntax where `.8` meant each element was 8 bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38035351/rgba-to-abgr-inline-arm-neon-asm-for-ios-xcode/38040651?noredirect=1#comment63616468_38040651).)

Comment: Thanks--  Do you have any suggestions on how I would go about converting these 4 files into intrinsics?

Comment: @patrick: nothing specific beyond the obvious "make C functions", but you'll probably have to rewrite them by hand.  I barely know NEON; I just picked up some bits of it from the same tags that I follow for x86 asm and SSE/AVX questions.

Comment: The NEON intrinsics have a more-or-less 1:1 mapping with the equivalent AArch32 instructions, which should permit a relatively mechanical transformation of the vector parts. Unpicking the scalar stuff (loop counters, conditional parts, function prologue/epilogue boilerplate, etc) back to C++ code is probably the more involved aspect, but the plain C++ and SSE intrinsic versions ought to provide relatively useful points of reference.