# Using inline ARM asm in Android NDK project

Tags: c++, assembly, android-ndk, arm

I'm doing a little project using the Android NDK, and I must insert some asm code for ARM architecture.

Everything apart from the asm works just fine, but the asm code tells me that

> Operand 1 should be an integer register

when conpiling simple code like

`asm("mov r0, r0");`

---

So, what is the problem? Is my computer trying to compile for x86_64 instead of ARM? If so, how should I change that?

Also, I've tried the x86_64 equivalent `arm("mov rax, rax");` but the error is the same.

Comment: Which ABIs are you building for?

Comment: Try `mov x0, x0`. If it doesn't give an error then your problem is that you're using 32-bit ARM assembly language with the 64-bit ARM toolchain. You either need to switch to 32-bit tools or 64-bit assembly language. By the way, you should investigate whether you really need to use inline assembly. It's hard to get right. See if you can't use intrinsics to do what you want instead.

Comment: When targeting x86, the default asm syntax is AT&T style, so `asm("mov %rax, %rax");` should work as a no-op.  Use `gcc -S` to generate an asm output file.  Look for `#APP` / `#NO_APP` around your code, and see if it looks like the surrounding compiler-generated asm.  e.g. https://godbolt.org/g/h8JIEy

Comment: Re: @Ross's last point, see https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm.  Also see [my answer on this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38035351/rgba-to-abgr-inline-arm-neon-asm-for-ios-xcode) for an example of how easy it is to get it wrong, and a stubborn OP that refuses to believe his asm is unsafe because it happens to work with his current surrounding code.

Comment: @RossRidge If I put `mov x0, x0` it says _too many memory references for `mov'_

Answer (score 2):

All your C sources are compiled for each architecture that is mentioned in your `APP_ABI`. So there is no point wondering why ARM assembly was not understood by x64 compiler or vice versa.

Do not use inline assembly. It is much better to put all assembly stuff into dedicated `*.S` sources, that will be processed by `as` (NDK toolchains have it). Those assembly sources should be placed into appropriate folders like `arch-arm/`, `arch-x86/`. Then you should add them to `Android.mk` properly:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := arch-$(TARGET_ARCH)/my_awesome_code.S
```

`$(TARGET_ARCH)` helps to resolve path to appropriate source in a correct and painless way.

P.S. Also standalone assembly gives more abilities to you than inline. This is one more reason to avoid using inline assembly. Moreover inline assembly syntax differs from compiler to compiler since it is not part of any standard.

Comment: Even doing that, having

`    .text
    .global MyAsmFunction
    .type   MyAsmFunction function

MyAsmFunction:
    mov x0,#2`
as my `.s` file, doing what you said and having `extern "C" void MyAsmFunction();` It outputs the error _expecting operand after ','; got nothing_, which is one of the error I got in inline asm.