# Which header file contain definition of register?

Tags: linux, reverse-engineering

I want to develop a hook library in Linux ( Android ) that need to access to general purpose register.

But I don't know which header file contains it. Can anyone tell me which header file contain the definition of the register ? And maybe how to access the register.

Consider the Android maybe run on `ARMv7` or `ARM64` or `x86`, Maybe there's a pattern of the header file, for example `#include <x86/register>`

Comment: You want to use registers from a C/C++ project on android? Inline assembly may help -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39084690/using-inline-arm-asm-in-android-ndk-project.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by accessing a general purpose register?